# How to update a value in a table from from

Tags: forms, ms-access

Sorry if this has been asked before but I really cant find an answer anywhere.

I want to change a specific value in a table,using a lable from a form.
I got very close with an Update Query,but then all the values in the column update.

Looks like this:
[image]

Sorry it not in english. So this is the transaction form,it can add,delete and save records.There's an attribute called Iznos Uplate(Deposit),all I want is for this label in the form to add 100€ to the field RAČUN.Stanje_Računa(Balance), which is the second picture

[image]

This is the Client form,it has a account subform which shows all the accounts that a client has.In the subform theres a field Stanje_Računa(which is balance)

So my question is, when im in the Transaction form and I want to create a new transaction, and input 100€ as a deposit(like in the pic),can I make it update that specific clients balance with 100€?

Thanks in advance,really looking forward to any kind of advice.

Comment: I solved the problem with an update query and a macro,if anyone is interested PM me